# Underscore how to filter the object using multiple values?

Tags: underscore.js

I have a array of values:

```
var removeAge = ['7', '8', '5', '11'];
```

and I would like to filter the object, which is not contains the 'removeAge' value on their age attribute

like :

```
var array = [
    {'name':'one', "age":'3'},
    {'name':'two', "age":'1'},
    {'name':'three', "age":'3'},
    {'name':'four', "age":'1'},
    {'name':'one', "age":'7'},
    {'name':'one', "age":'5'},
    {'name':'one', "age":'7'},
    {'name':'one', "age":'8'},
    {'name':'one', "age":'7'},
    {'name':'one', "age":'11'},
    {'name':'one', "age":'7'}
]
```

how can i remove the object, whichever contains one of the age from 'removeAge' contains? so the result become objects like :

```
var array = [
    {'name':'one', "age":'3'},
    {'name':'two', "age":'1'},
    {'name':'three', "age":'3'},
    {'name':'four', "age":'1'},
]
```

I tried like this, but no result: totally wrong!

```
_.each(remove, function(val) {
    return _.filter(array, function(){
        return item.age != val
    })
} )
```

any one help me to sort this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be done like this:

```
_.reject(array, function(item){ return removeAge.indexOf(item['age']) != -1; });
```

Comment: A bit more idiomatic way: 
`_.filter(array, function(item){ return _.contains(removeAge, item.age) })`

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.map(removeAge, function (n, i) {
    array = jQuery.grep(array, function (value) {
        return value.age != n;
    });
});
```